# Paytm Transaction Status API thows error TXN_FAILURE always

Tags: paytm

I am trying to get the status of Paytm transaction
but the response which I am getting from the Paytm server is always this `TXN_FAILURE`

- Anyone please help me what mistake I am doing here

I am using correct `order_id` and `mid`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check Transaction Status API on our Paytm Developer portal which should work. Please find a sample curl request for the same

curl -X POST 'https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/v3/order/status' 
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' 
--data '{"body":{"mid":"{mid}","orderId":"{order-id}"},"head":{"signature":"{signature}"}}'